# Using a numpy array of length less than pandas dataframe to fill in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-10', freq='D'), columns=['test'])

vals = np.array([1.0, 2.0])

df['test'] = vals
```

I get this error:
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Any way I can fix it? This error is arising because lenght of `vals` is less than length of `df`. I want to insert numpy NaNs for the places where I have no values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign to just the first rows like this:

```
df['test'][:len(vals)] = vals
```

Comment: sweet! so obvious now that you have posted the soln